# Count() occurrences in a separate table

Tags: sql, sqlite

This might just be a case of the mondays, but my brain cant seem to figure out the query I need to run to get the results I need.

I have two tables; `Message` and `MessageTo`. `Message` records an original message - eg, Title, Body, DateSent etc etc. `MessageTo` records *instances* of that message being sent to a recipient. Eg, multiple rows in the `MessageTo` table might point to a single row in the `Message` table - meaning one message has been sent to multiple people. The basic information in the `MessageTo` table is the messageId, recipientId, acknowledgedDate and a few others.

What I need is a query that returns `Message`s with a count showing how many people it has been sent to (eg, how many times that messageId appears on the `MessageTo` table).

My first attempt at this was to make one query to get a list of `Message`s, and then do a second query to get the number of occurrences on the `MessageTo` table. However, I'd like to do this **using only one query, if possible** - as this process will be repeated many times and I'd like to make it as stream-lined as possible. Repeated multiple database queries is not ideal. Any help is much appreciated.

I am using `SQLite` if that makes a difference, although I think it's pretty compatible with alot of other versions of SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along this line should work. You did not list the field that identified each message uniquely so I'm using "MessageId and you should change to what applies in your db.

```
Select
  m.*
, (Select Count(*) From MessageTo mt where mt.MessageId = m.MessageId) As Cnt
From Message m
```

Comment: Thanks, you jogged my memory!